# Writing MongoDB Queries using "in" modifier

Tags: java, mongodb

How can we write query in mongodb which is equals to the inner select sql query.

```
select field1, field2 
from workflowTable 
where id in(select idField from usersTable)
```

No of hits to the db should be same.

Answer (score 2):

Let's think you have 3 documents.collection name is users.

```
   {
    "_id": ObjectId("4efa8d2b7d284dad101e4bc9"),
    "Last Name": "DUMONT",
    "First Name": "Jean",
    "alert":1,
    "Date of Birth": "01-22-1963"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4efa8d2b7d284dad101e4bc7"),
    "Last Name": "PELLERIN",
    "First Name": "Franck",
    "alert":2,
    "Date of Birth": "09-19-1983",
    "Address": "1 chemin des Loges",
    "City": "VERSAILLES"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4efa8d2b7d284dad101e4bc7"),
    "Last Name": "PELLERIN",
    "First Name": "Franck",
    "alert":3,
    "Date of Birth": "09-19-1983",
    "Address": {
        "Street": "1 chemin des Loges",
        "City": "VERSAILLES"
    }
}
```

In above document i want only 2 document which column contain alert 1 and 2.Query for that

```
db.users.find({alert:{$in:[1,2]}})
```

This will give me first two document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $in parameter in mongodb for this query. Check [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in) tutorial for more information.